# Django Cassandra engine - how to define table name

Tags: django, cassandra

I am using [Django Cassandra](https://pypi.org/project/django-cassandra-engine/) and I have defined my model, which I have this to name a table:

```
    class Meta:
    db_table = "table_name"
```

However, Cassandra doesn't create the table with my custom name. What am I missing?

Comment: Hello, your indention is incorrect, you need tabulation before the db_table= "table_name". Can we also have the entire model you want to create please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/models.html

> **table_name** = None Optional. Sets the name of the CQL table for this model. If left blank, the table name will be the name of the
>   model, with it’s module name as it’s prefix. Manually defined table
>   names are not inherited.

```
class Meta:
    __table_name__ = "table_name"
```